# swtableviewcell how to create a utilitybutton that can change state when i press it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using SWTableViewCell, I have a right utility button, I want this button to change when I press it. Just like the mail app, press the button "mark as unread", the button's state will change into "mark as read". How do I manage to do that?

---

here's some code

```
        CommodityDetailsCell *cell = (CommodityDetailsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCommodityDetailsCell];
    [cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self collectionButton] WithButtonWidth:79];
    cell.delegate = self;
```

---

```
- (NSArray *)collectionButton {
NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
[rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor: UIColorFromRGB(0x208fff) title:@"收藏"];
return rightUtilityButtons;}
```

---

```
- (NSArray *)cancelCollectionButton {
NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
[rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor redColor] title:@"取消收藏"];

return rightUtilityButtons;}
```

---

I want the cell's right utility button to be the collectionButton at first, change into cancelCollectionButton when pressed, change back when pressed again.
Don't know if I've made this clear. Hope you'll make sense of it.

Comment: post your code for more help.

Comment: do you mean you want to change the button title by pressing it?

Comment: not just the title, I need these two buttons to handle different things. And I don't know how to implement their delegate. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I figure it out myself, thank you guys anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and finally I solved it.
Because `cell.leftUtilityButtons` it's an NSArray it's immutable and so you cannot do plenty of stuff with the swipe buttons. So what I did is to initiate an `NSMutableArray` with `cell.leftUtilityButtons` and replace the object with the old image of the selected swipe button with the object includes the image I need. And point back the `cell.leftUtilityButtons` to my temporary mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *leftUtilityButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:cell.leftUtilityButtons];
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray new];
[temp sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:kMainColor
                              icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"]];
[leftUtilityButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
cell.leftUtilityButtons = leftUtilityButtons;
```

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your question, could you accept it as correct?